# Most time efficient way to check whether each string in a list is a substring

Tags: java, string, algorithm, design-patterns, matching

Given a list of subsrings and a string, print out the item in the list if it is a substring.

What's the most time/space efficient way to do this without using any built in methods (contains, .substring, etc)?

**Example:**

Input: list: `["cat", "dog", "foo", "foopoo", "foopo", "nope", "dogf"]`

string: "cardogfoopoo"`

output: 
dog
foo
foopoo
foopo
dogf

**My idea:**

So my idea so far is that you would loop through the string given and map each character to an arraylist of indices

<(c, [0]), (a, [1]), (r, [2]), (d, [3]), (o, [4,7,8,10,11]), (g, [5]), (f, [6]), (p, [4])>

and then you loop through the list of substrings.

```
for (int x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {
    String s = list.get(x);
    if (s.get(s.charAt(0)) != null)
         //loop through, comparing from whether the word is in the string
```

**Explanation:**

"c" is in the map at index 0.

Loop through the length of "cat" and compare if its the same as from 0 to the length of "cat"

### If yes, print.

but this doesn't take advantage of the fact that if "foo" was already found to be a substring, it should be easy to check if "foopoo" is a substring (without looping through foo already)

I'm a bit stuck there because I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this. Without using "contains" or whatnot (which is NOT more time efficient)

Comment: Do those substrings always start from first character?

Comment: no - for example, "dog" is a substring but it doesn't start from the first character!

Comment: The fastest way to find multiple substrings fast is a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)

Comment: @aaronman i thought of that! although i'm not too sure of its implementation and how to check in java. is there a DP approach to this also (one that might be less efficient) ?

Comment: @user2457563 there are implementations of suffix trees all over the internet (why languages choose not to implement them by default I'm not sure). What's the point of asking for a fast approach if you decide something is too complex (and suffix tree's are not that complex). IMO if wikipedia has an article about something it's probably not that complex

Comment: @aaronman give me an example of something that doesn't have a wikipedia article because it's "too complex for wikipedia" (note, this was a paraphrased quote, and not a direct quote.)

Comment: @Cruncher well there are plenty of CS things that are too specific to be on wikipedia, but after a quick search I noticed inpace merge only gets a mention on wikipedia not a full explanation. yet because of it's memory efficiency (even though it's big O is slightly slower) it is often used in implementations of merge sort

Comment: @Cruncher also keep in mind I didn't say suffix trees were easy, but they are certainly not so difficult they should be avoided

Comment: @aaronman : *"IMO if wikipedia has an article about something it's probably not that complex"* Seriously?  So Quantum Fields isn't complex, then?  Or mabye Euler's formula?  They are to me.  But I'm just not that smart, I guess.

Comment: @MadConan 1. Am I a physicist or mathematician, nope, we don't need to know that stuff. On the other hand we are supposed to be computer scientists, we should know the topics on computer science. 2. I didn't make that point to argue about wikipedia IDC, the point you should focus on is that suffix tree's are not that complex and SO has a serious problem where the OP will complain about a perfectly good solution (often the best solution) being too complicated, that is a terrible attitude.